# UE5 C++ - Unable to find 'struct' with name 'FActorSpawnParameters' with header included

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4, unreal-engine5

I'm working on a game and I'm trying to create a function. On trying to rebuild it give me the error 'Unable to find 'struct' with name 'FActorSpawnParameters' for the header file. *.cpp no errors

##### PBWeapon_Base.h

```
#pragma once

#include "CoreMinimal.h"
#include "Gameplay/Items/PBItem_Base.h"
#include "GameplayTagContainer.h"
#include "Utility/PBMathLib.h"
#include "Engine/World.h"
#include "PBChildWeaponComponent.h"
#include "PBWeapon_Base.generated.h"

...

UFUNCTION(Server, reliable)
        void FireProjectileRPC(TSubclassOf<class APBProjectile> ProClass, FVector MLocation, FRotator MRotation, FActorSpawnParameters SParams, UWorld* MWorld);
```

##### PBWeapon_Base.cpp

```
#include "Gameplay/Items/PBWeapon_Base.h"
#include "Gameplay/Items/PBProjectile.h"
#include "Engine/SkeletalMeshSocket.h"
#include "Gameplay/Soldier/PBInventoryInterfaceLib.h"
#include "Gameplay/Soldier/PBSoldierInterfaceLib.h"

...

void FireProjectileRPC_Implementation(TSubclassOf<APBProjectile> ProClass, FVector MLocation, FRotator MRotation, FActorSpawnParameters SParams, UWorld* MWorld) {

    ...
}
```

Added different headers and includes but still same build error in the header file

Comment: Perhaps you're capitalizing it incorrectly? Try `FactorSpawnParameters` ("Fa").

Comment: @paulsm4 https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.27/en-US/API/Runtime/Engine/Engine/FActorSpawnParameters/ no it's the right spelling

Comment: I am not sure if `FActorSpawnParameters` is supported for RPC calls. Could you add more code? Because in none of your code snippets, I can actually see the include.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't really be providing several of those parameters via an RPC, keep in mind this is data being sent over the network, you want this to be as lightweight as possible.

That being said, the reason you are receiving the error you are is because  if my memory serves correct, FActorSpawnParameters isn't a `USTRUCT`, meaning you cannot use it in functions that're marked as `UFUNCTION`, this is becuase UBT (Unreal Build Tool) cannot generate reflection code for it.

With the above in mind, I would suggest you rethink your implementation of your `FireProjectileRPC_Implementation` function, `FVector MLocation` and `FRotator MRotation` are "acceptible" (though if this is within a weapon actor class, you could use a muzzle socket on the mesh or component within the actor itself to determine those).

Without any more specifics of your implementation, some basic suggestions I would emplore you to consider are.

- Using a `uint8` inheriting `UENUM` with a `GetProjectileClass` helper
  function to determine the class you need to spawn (since this will
  allow for 255 total classes and also consume considerably less
  bandwidth).
- Drop the World parameter entirely, since `GetWorld()` is a function
  that is typically available in all main Unreal classes (definitely
  `AActor`).
- Construct your `FActorSpawnParameters` within the implementation of `FireProjectilRPC` (assuming this is to spawn a project from a weapon class, using `GetOwner()` within the weapon actor will return the owner of the weapon, providing it is set correctly it will be your "character").

If you can provide some more information with code, I'd be happy to make some additional suggestions.